# Extracting the text from the href of an anchor tag using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm kinda of a novice when it comes to using `Regex` and I've kinda stumbled upon some issues. I'm trying to get the text that's inside the `href` of a link.

This is what I've come up so far

```
/\w+(?=")/g
```

And these are the strings I'm testing it on:

```
<a target="_blank" href="fdsfsd">fdsfs</a>
<a href="mdosfsd"></a>
<link href="f89sdfsd" />
```

Right now it returns any text that's inside a **""**, but I don't know how can I select if there's more to that **""** in this case if it's a `href` and if this `href` is part of `<a>`

Comment: Use `getAttribute('href')`

Comment: Still want to use RegEx: [`href=(['"])(.*?)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/sU8aN3/1) and get second captured group

Comment: You don't understand I want to do it only with regex, no **JS functions** or **Jquery selectors**.

Comment: That's why I added second comment

Comment: But this returns **href="text"** I want to get only the text. I've already went this road, that's why in my regex I'm starting with `\w+`

Comment: Are you running JavaScript on a live page being rendered or are you statically looking at an HTML file?

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar that's not the point here

Comment: from what language do you plan on executing said regex from?

Comment: brother, why do hard stuffs, when JS is there free of cost.

Comment: @user1915308, BTW, what's your point?

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar okay look at this way, maybe the example I'm giving is not good. Let's say you get a string like this "This is too long so comment='dfdsfsd', comment='348958345', comment='fg908fdgkdf'". And I want to get everything that's inside **comment**. I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: @user1915308 May you share a piece of your current js code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Element.getAttribute()`. Read about it on the Mozilla Developer Network [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Here's an example:

`var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);`

Also note: it's bad practice to parse html using Regular Expressions. See here - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You *can* use regex to parse HTML if you're doing something like a find and replace in your editor, or working with a limited set of data.

Comment: I know how to get content of attribute using JS functions or Jquery selectors that's not the point here

Comment: Why do you want to get it using regex?

Comment: @user1915308 `/href="(.+)"/`

Comment: @KarlTaylor like I said above this will return href="test" I only want the test inside the href and to check if that href is part of <a> and not let's say <link>

Comment: The regex I provided matches `test`, check the match information. You can use String.prototype.match() to do stuff with your match. -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: ok, let's say if "fn" is the function you are using for regex match, then     var pre_match = fn(/href="(.+)"/, string);    var last_match = fn(/\w+/, pre_match);

Answer (score 0):

A solution purely using regex, although generally not advisable (as discussed above) is:

```
var re = /href="[^"]*"/gi,
    extracted = yourText.match(re).map(v => v.slice(6, -1));
```

Note that this is flawed many ways - for instance, what if the `href` is defined using single quotes(`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`)? Or, what if there is white-space? Or, a false-positive attribute such as `not-an-href="..."`

This solution should only be used in simple scenarios, where full robustness against odd edge cases like this is not an issue.